# Is bufferevent_flush not necessary for a socket-based bufferevent in libevent?

Tags: c, asynchronous, networking, network-programming, libevent

From the [documentation of libevent](https://www.seul.org/%7Enickm/libevent-book/Ref6_bufferevent.html):

> Currently (as of Libevent 2.0.5-beta), `bufferevent_flush()` is only
> implemented for some bufferevent types. ***In particular, socket-based
> bufferevents don’t have it.***

I tested the following code:

```
auto output = ::bufferevent_get_output(bev);
::evbuffer_add(output, "hello", 5);
// ::bufferevent_flush(bev, EV_WRITE, BEV_FLUSH);
```

Note that I commented out the last line `::bufferevent_flush(bev, EV_WRITE, BEV_FLUSH);`, but the data was still sent immediately.

**Is** `bufferevent_flush` **not necessary for a socket-based bufferevent in libevent? If so, how libevent decides when to send the pending data in evbuffer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, libevent is relying on the buffering services of the underlying socket implementation.

For TCP/IP, this involves sending any buffered data either when the `send` buffer is full or a short while after no new data has been added ([Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)), whichever happens first.  Since this delay is typically only a few hundred milliseconds, you may not have noticed it.

There *is* a call to `setsockopt` to disable this delay (`TCP_NODELAY`) and it's possible that libevent is using that, in which case any data passed to `send` is transmitted immediately.  You'd probably have to inspect the source to see if that's what they're actually doing (it would be unusual).